# Track certain parameters on some command

Tags: bash, shell, function

Let's say that I have a command `git branch` (always with a couple of words) for example.

What I want is to keep track of when this command is executed with arguments. For example, if I execute the command `git branch develop` without errors, I want to save `develop` on a file.

I tried to overwrite git command on my `.bash_profile`, something like this:

```
git () {
    if [ $# -eq 3 ]
    then
        git $@
        echo $2 > /path/tacked_parameters.txt
    else
        git $@
    fi
}
```

But seems that does not work well. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: according to your example (git branch develop) you want to check if "$#" is "2" and not "3" ? ... (2 parameters to the git function)

Comment: Was a mistake, but the code is just an example

Comment: ok. I added additional remarks underneath Stephane's (good) answer. my remarks may not be applicable (I think of the .txt as a log file, but it could be something else that can't have dates in it?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've got a few problems here:

- your `git` function is calling itself recursively instead of the original `git` command.
- you're using `$@` unquoted which doesn't make any sense whatsoever
- you're [leaving other variables unquoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells), asking the shell to split+glob them.
- you're [using `echo` for arbitrary data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).
- you're losing the exit status of the original `git` command.
- you're overwriting your log file upon each invocation.
- you're putting function definitions in your `~/.bash_profile` which is meant to customize your login session, not your shell and is normally not read by non-login `bash` invocations.

You'd want something like:

```
git() {
  if [ "$#" -eq 3 ]
  then
    local ret
    command git "$@"; ret=$?
    printf '%s\n' "$2" >> /path/tacked_parameters.txt
    return "$ret"
  else
    command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

That is:

- quote your variables,
- use `command` to run the `git` *command*,
- save the exit status of `git` in a local variables an return it on exit,
- use `>>` instead of `>` for redirection to the log file.
- use `printf` instead of `echo`.
- and put that in your `~/.bashrc` instead (making sure your `~/.bash_profile` is sourcing `~/.bashrc` as login `bash` shells don't read `~/.bashrc` by default (a `bash` bug/misfeature)). Unless you want to export that `git` function (with `export -f git`) in case you also want `bash` scripts that call `git` to call that function.

Comment: Amazing explanation and works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 for a very good answer. But the op may need to change the check to `[ "$#" -eq 2 ]` , according to his example. And it could be a good idea to also add the date to "tacked_parameters.txt". And I'd go for the general case (ie, not just track of the 2nd parameters when 2 parameters, but track any parameters) : I'd get rid of the if, and have: `printf '%s: %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')" "$0 $*"` ? (ie, show the command + all the parameters (note that you still lose some info, for example which parameter's had intra-separators, if any). Portable date *close* to the iso8601 standard)